# Drag and Drop - How to keep an attribute updated?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have an edit form in which I can drag and drop images. I also have an array, order, which contains the order of my images and is accessible in my controller. How can I make it so that the array, order, is updated every time I move something in my list, so that I get the right order list in my controller?

Answer (score 0):

you can easily drag image using **jquery-ui draggable()** method

Refer : https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#scroll

Comment: in dragable you have to perform ajax call to store the change order of DOM in file and when page is include that file only... see in console if when you drag image dom is change its order and it's attribute value..
Refer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-9d1bMYYuPo